# Using validation to check a persons age from todays date

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create a to check if a person is between 18 and 25 as of today's date and time. I know I could use a range validator with a date type then manually type in the dates but if someone used the form in the future the dates I typed in would be incorrect. Is there a piece of code I could use to make sure I wouldn't have to keep going back to update the validator every year?

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rngValDateOfBirth.MinimumValue = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-25).ToString();
        rngValDateOfBirth.MaximumValue = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18).ToString();
    }

 Date Of Birth <asp:TextBox ID="txtCdob" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCdob" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You must enter a date of  birth" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtCDOB" Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="rngValDateOfBirth" runat="server" ErrorMessage="must be between 18 and 25" ControlToValidate="txtCdob" Type="Date"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cam set the [Minimum/Maximum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.RangeValidator_properties.aspx) properties in the codebehind.

Untested, but something like this might work:

```
MyDateRangeValidator.MinimumValue = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-25).ToString(/* format */);
MyDateRangeValidator.MaximumValue = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18).ToString(/* format */);
```

Comment: Why the `ToString`s? It'd be easier to compare `DateTime`s as `DateTime`s.

Comment: @TimS., those properties are string values. The control can handle the conversion to DateTimes. See the Remarks section. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.minimumvalue.aspx

Comment: oh, gotcha, I didn't realize that this was an existing class with `string` properties.

Comment: I seem to be getting an error when I run the web page saying that "The value " of the MaximumValue property of 'rngValDateOfBirth' cannot be converted to type 'Date'. Does this mean that my range validator needs to be a string type rather than a date type as I have it set. I've tried that but then when I enter a correct date into the textbox the error message of my range validator is appearing even though it's correct. Thanks again.

Comment: @John, is that the exact error message? Because there is no type `Date`. Can you update your question with the exact code and exact error message?

Comment: I've updated my post with the code, and here's a screen cap of the error. Thanks for all your help. http://i1170.photobucket.com/albums/r527/trecoolo/error_zps9ea77ac3.jpg

Comment: @John, you don't set that code on the button click. The page is complaining because it needs to be set when the control is initialized, not afterwards, otherwise it's trying to convert a blank string to a date type. Try putting it in your page load, and don't forget you need to format the date as a date, if you just call ToString(), it includes the Time portion which you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.Now` to get the current date & time (or `DateTime.UtcNow` to avoid timezone concerns).  Having this you can calculate someone's age dynamically from their DOB, so no need to update any code on a regular basis.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
int age = DateTime.Now.Year - userBirthYear;
if(age > 18 && age < 25)
{

}
```

DateTime.Now will get the correct time when it is called